# wiil one very large UIView for long scrolling in UIScrollView cause resource issues?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

In terms of creating an infinite scrolling capability using a UIScrollView (no looping back to the start), for a calendar in fact, will one very large UIView for long scrolling in UIScrollView cause resource issues?

Assumptions:

1. That is assuming one programmatically adds/removing subviews onto this main backplane view as it is about to need being shown/visible, then removing afterwards.
2. Don't want to use UICollectionView (to focus question on use of UIScrollView please)

Requirements:

1. Would want to put UI View onto this background plane as well as drawing to it directly, e.g. adding lines.
2. So therefore would need to be adding/removing things like Lines drawn as well UILabels.  (well haven't delved into Lines and whether they would need to be drawn in their own subview, upon which you're then adding removing these "line" subviews, as opposed to drawing directly onto the main backplane view in drawrect)

Background:

- I see some suggestions of having 3 "pages" (views) and you keep moving these as scrolling occurs, however this just seems more complicated.

Comment: You are basically asking to recreate UITableView / UICollectionView because this is what they do.  They keep a pool of cells and when you call dequeReusableCell you get one from the pool, or if its empty you get a new one.  When the cells go off screen they get put back into the que to be recycled.  In this way, and app like music can represent a datasource with 10,000+ songs with only 10-12 table view cells, because thats all that's visible at any given time.

Comment: yes - partly a learning process

Comment: I understand your words and thoughts about "no collection view" view, but I totally recommend you to check the article [Custom Collection View Layouts](https://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/collection-view-layouts/) because they're discussing exactly your case with a calendar and have some good points about the implementation. I think it would be helpful.

Comment: What about performance issues, I don't understand your solution. UIScrollView is already UIView and you could control the size via `.contentSize` property and add your subviews directly to UIScrollView. But in my opinion this kind of UI is unsupportable and hard to maintain. For example, you'll have a lot of issues with iPad support or orientation changes and etc.

Comment: hi @dive - ok understood - so I'm effectively really asking is it ok to set the ".contentSize" to be very large without resource issues.  I would guess you could, as the real issue would be managing the subviews you're putting onto this, however wanted to double check.

Comment: @dive re orientation changes I assume you just mean re-laying out?   I've actually implemented a UICollectionView & wasn't a huge fan of all the various extensions methods/callbacks you go through...

Comment: actually just noted this in the Apple doco however they did not highlight why a large view my not be "practical"  "One place where applications often lay out subviews manually is when implementing a large scrollable area. Because it is impractical to have a single large view for its scrollable content, applications often implement a root view that contains a number of smaller tile views. Each tile represents a portion of the scrollable content. When a scroll event happens, the root view calls its setNeedsLayout method to initiate a layout change. Its layoutSubviews method then reposition..."

Comment: @Greg, you're right about the management of this kind of solution. Of course, theoretically and practically, you can create any view you want with any `.contentSize` you can imagine, but (if I understand your initial question correctly) you're talking about experiment / learning lesson, so I spoke about potential problems with which you'll be faced with high probability on the basis of my experience. Basically, I suggest you to turn your experiment in a more rational direction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should not be any resource issue as far as you use views.
I developed kinda map application with the next view structure.

```
MapScrollView (UIScrollView)
  - TileContainerView (UIView)
    - TileContainerSubViews[10..] (UIView)
      - TileLayer [] (CALayer)
  - UIButton[]
  - IconLayer[] (CALayer)
  - TrackLineLayer (CALayer)
  - .....
```

All of the Tile**Views in hierarchy and MapScrollView share the same size, which is aligned to the size of the TileContainerSubViews[n], which further holds many TileLayer(s) with size of 256x256. The largest TileContainerSubView[] can hold as many as 10000x10000 TileLayer(s)
which is 2560000x2560000 in view size. (Of course, we can't actually add that many layers due to resource issue.) All of views/layers are added/removed on the way.

Note you can create large UIView but not CALayer.
When I tryed to create huge CALayer, the program terminated with some error message. CATiledLayer doesn't seem to have this constraint but I haven't tested.

Comment: thanks - was there any open source version of what you were doing there you come across within the IOS dev community by chance?

Comment: Put sample code at https://github.com/beshio/sample-code. The code is for reference only. This is the first iOS program I wrote, so it’s messy and may be doing stupid things. Anyway, in line 1991, it sets view’s frame with (256xsome_large_number).